# How can I made a dynamic checkbox alert with onclick function?

Tags: jquery, html, debugging, checkbox

I have the following function below that creates multiple check boxes in a table. 
Problem: I cannot get the value for each box checked.

```
function createRoutesTable(result)
    {
        var length = result.jsonList.length;
        var tablecontents = "";
        console.log(length);
        tablecontents ="<table>";
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            tablecontents += "<tr>"
            tablecontents += "<td><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox_"+ i + "' value='" + result.jsonList[i].Id +"' onclick = 'createAlerts()'><td>"
            tablecontents += "</tr>"
        }
        tablecontents +="</table>";
        document.getElementById("tablespace").innerHTML = tablecontents;

    }
```

Here is my function below:

```
function createAlerts()
{

     if( $('#checkbox_1').is(':checked'))
     {
         alert($(this).val());
     }

}
```

This will work for the first box, but I need a way for everytime I click any box, it will grab the appropriate value. I really don't want to have to write brittle code and write this if statement for each checkbox I created. That's really bad.

Put another way, no matter if I click checkbox_3 or checkbox_6, I will get the value for that checkbox. I thought about trying it this [way](http://jsfiddle.net/heten/19/), but I need this to work with a function when I use "onclick", so I got stuck.

Please help. I will give + rep where I can on responses to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you are using plain JavaScript everywhere else, why not stick with it? Pass the current checkbox as a parameter.

With the least amount of change you can do something similar to this:

```
function createAlerts(theCheckbox) {
    if (theCheckbox.checked) {
        alert(theCheckbox.value);
    }
}
```

Update your binding code to include this:

```
onclick = 'createAlerts(this)'
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rSs7z/) - Using plain JavaScript

---

Either go with jQuery or plain JavaScript but mixing `getElementById` and jQuery selectors is more than confusing when maintaining the code in the long run.

If you want to use a more jQuery orientated solution for the binding you can use [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with delegation.

jQuery in this case sets the context of `this` to the clicked element so you don't need to manually pass the parameter, similar to this.

```
function createAlerts() {
    if (this.checked) {
        alert(this.value);
    }
}
```

You can then change your current binding function, leaving out the inline `createAlert` binding, similar to this:

```
function createRoutesTable(result) {
    var length = result.jsonList.length;
    var tablecontents = "";
    console.log(length);
    tablecontents = "<table>";
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        tablecontents += "<tr>"
        tablecontents += "<td><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox_"+ i + "' value='" + result.jsonList[i].Id +"'><td>"
        tablecontents += "</tr>"
    }
    tablecontents += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("tablespace").innerHTML = tablecontents;
}
```

Then when the DOM is ready bind the click event using `on()`, similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tablespace').on('click', 'table tr td [id^="checkbox_"]', createAlerts);
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/F8xmp/) - Using jQuery `on()`

---

The `createAlerts` function still uses `this` directly as there is no need for the additional overhead in wrapping a jQuery selector around the element `$(this)` when accessing native attributes.

The `^` is the [**attribute-starts-with selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), selecting any element starting with an id of `checkbox_` inside a dynamically generated `table tr td`.

The above uses `on()` with delegation, binding the click event to the closest static parent element, assuming above `#tablespace` but targeting the dynamic generated checkboxes within.

If `#tablespace` is also dynamic use `$(document).on(....)` or `$('body').on(....)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just use jQuery to bind the events . And remove the inline event bind to it.

This should also work for dynamically added elements

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=checkbox]', function() {
     if( $(this).is(':checked'))  //  or  this.checked
     {
         alert($(this.).val());
     }

});
```

Comment: If I click checkbox_1, and then later I click checkbox_2. Even if I unchecked checkbox_1, I will get the alert for checkbox_2 twice. Is there a way I can reset this after I do an alert?

Comment: I don't see how this could happen, the event handler is only firing for the element which has triggered the event (ie the checkbox which changed state).

If you're getting all the alerts, you must be iterating through all the checkboxes, or storing the state somewhere.

Have a look at my example which does what I think you're asking, it has some logging on the page so you can see the handlers without having to ok lots of alerts.

http://jsfiddle.net/jbergler/JzQJg/

Comment: Yes, I am saving $(this).val() as a var within the function. That must be messing up things somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Because you inputs were added after dom you cannot call them directly. `.on` can delegate. So try this code:

```
function createAlerts()
{
     $(document).on('change',input[type=checkbox],function(){
         if( $(this).is(':checked'))
         {
             alert($(this.).val());
         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just give it a class....

In this line...

```
 tablecontents += "<td><input type='checkbox' class='check' id='checkbox_"+ i + "' value='" + result.jsonList[i].Id +"'><td>"
```

Then in your jquery

```
  $(document).on('click','.check', function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
    alert($(this).val());}
  });
```

Or with your function...

```
$(document).on('click','.check', createAlerts);
```

Comment: Why add a class simply to match nodes? You can use the `:checkbox` selector and if you need to be specific narrow it down `#parentId > :checkbox`

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a handler to the click event on your checkboxes, jquery also supports delegated event handlers (with .on()) which let you bind to all matches on a selector even if new nodes are created after the call.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jbergler/JzQJg/

```
//dynamically bind to any 'checkbox' elements for a click handler
$(document).on("click", ":checkbox", function (e) {
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked") ? "yes" : "no";
    $("#log").append("Click on element: " + $(this).attr('id') + " Checked: " + checked + "\n");
});
```